# What is the best way to use IWshRuntimeLibrary in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a C# program which needs to use IWshRuntimeLibrary. The resulting executable needs to run on x86 and x64 variants of Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and current and (as far as possible) future flavours of Windows 10.

Exactly what I use from IWshRuntimeLibrary isn't important, but for the curious, I am using it to create shortcuts. In order to use it, the following has to be in the C# source:

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
```

Since there is no IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll, this unsurprisingly fails to compile.
If using the VisualStudio GUI, WSH can be added to the project and VS will handle it under the covers, but if using csc from the command line, as I am, this works instead:

```
tlbimp /machine:agnostic C:\Windows\system32\wshom.ocx
csc -win32res:PBM.res -l:IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll PBM.cs
```

In either case, wshom.ocx becomes usable by the resulting executable. So far, so
good.

My question as to whether this is the best way to do this is simple. Since the
executable was built using my wshom.ocx, will it work on other Windows systems?

I'm building using W7 x64, which is of course the oldest of systems I need to
support. Will the resulting executable run on x86 systems (tlbimp used
`/machine:agnostic` and csc defaults to `-platform:anycpu`, so I think it should?) Will it run on newer systems? I don't have a huge variety to test it on.

If not, what is needed to make it run, or just a better way to do it? I assume
that building on W10 instead would not be a good idea since its newer wshom.ocx
may well be incompatible with older systems. Documentation on this seems to be
thin at best!

Comment: Taking a dependency on the scripting host when you already have a perfectly fine programming language to work in seems iffy. You could take a dependency on the shell instead and create it directly (see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e23a82c-8bed-4b96-8b9a-4c2b6136a622/changing-the-icon-of-exe-files-programatically?forum=csharpgeneral), for example). This doesn't change the general thrust of your question, actually, since you'd still be taking a dependency on a COM library, but at least it removes one level of indirection.

Comment: What do you need from the wshom.ocx?  Perhaps there are alternatives to that.

Comment: Jeroen, as you say, this doesn't answer the question, merely moves it. Chris, I did say what I'm using it for, but I'm not looking for a different way to do it, I want to know how best to use IWshRuntimeLibrary.

Comment: I can now partially answer my own question: when built on W7 x64, it works on W8.1 x86. Still need to test it on more variants of Windows especially W10 1903.